# Mercurial: How to switch to a named branch if a tag has the same name?

Tags: version-control, mercurial, branch, repository, dvcs

I am just playing around with Mercurial at the moment and this may never come up as an issue, but I just created a repository and added some changes.  I tagged it at one point then created a named branch at another.  Both the tag and the branch have the same name. If I do `hg update name` it switches to the tagged version.  Is there any way to switch to the branch other than by using a revision number on the branch?

I think what made me think about this was that if we were to write some scripts for automatically building a particular revision we would want to just specify either a tag or a branch to build from.  If someone happened to use the same name in a tag and a branch then we would run into problems with the script getting the correct revisions.  Is the only solution to this to make sure that they are unique, e.g. by pre-pending branch or tag to the name?

Comment: +1 for forward thinking.  Exactly what you are describing happened to me: I created a tag when I meant branch, then deleted the tag, then my build/deploy script (which takes branch as an argument) started doing the wrong thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get the tip revision of the branch by parsing the output of `hg branches`.

Consider this situation (a branch and a tag, both named `popular`):

```
$ hg tags
tip                            3:afb4026bfe32
popular                        1:cea974d8cfc4
$ hg branches
default                        3:afb4026bfe32
popular                        2:aa7ede2bb3f6
```

In bash-like shells, you get the tip revision of *branch* `popular` with:

```
$ hg branches | grep popular | awk -F ':' '{print $2}'
```

Getting the *tag* revision works similar, using `hg tags`.

Now your script is able to update to the branch/tag in question.

Comment: Thanks, this will work I guess (just had to add -w to grep for an exact match).

Comment: Instead of the bash line, you could also use:

`$ hg log -b popular -l 1 --template '{node|short}\n'`

:-)

Comment: @ChristopheMuller, I find that that doesn't always work.  You have to have that branch in the history of your current revision.  Whereas this answer works in either case (although I use `cut -d':' -f2` instead of `awk` :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you could do it with:

```
hg update -r "limit(heads(branch(name)),1)"
```

which uses the revsets feature (see `hg help revsets` in a newer Mercurial).

But were it me I'd just delete the tag after beating the person who created it about the head and neck.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work.  It updates to the tip (which is on the default branch).  If I update to another branch where there is no conflict it works.